# How to compare indexes in for...of loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

What is the right way to compare indexes inside a for...of loop in JS?

So, my goal is to convert for loop to for...of loop and get same results

This:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   if (items[i] === items[i+1]) {
   //...
   }
}
```

To this:

```
for (const [item, i] of items.entries()) {
  //if i === i+1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) instead would would make more sense for your code since returns the items' keys:

```
for (const i in items) {
   if (items[i] === items[i+1]) {
   //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, e.g:

```js
const arr = [0, 7, 2, 6, 5, 9, 6, 9];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
  console.log(accumulator, ":", currentValue);
  if (accumulator > currentValue) console.log("Tada!");
  return currentValue;
};


arr.reduce(reducer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the forEach method to do this :

```
items.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (item == items[i + 1]) {
        // ...
    }
});
```